# Requirejs-config is not writable

Tags: magento2, requirejs-config.js

After Magento2.2.6 Installation,getting this error. Even assign 777 permission.

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The path "frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js:///home/vnsmenco/public_html/pub/static/" is not writable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the following commands to assign permissions:

```
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
Or 
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/vnsmenco/public_html/pub/static/
```

I hope your home directory looke like this

```
/home/vnsmenco/public_html/Magento files here
```

Comment: funny thing is, whole directory of `Static` have 777 permission.

Comment: now JS and CSS are not loading, even change `di.xml` ( Symlink -> Copy )

Comment: Did you check now the permissions?  js and CSS will be solved next if your basic issue is addressed.

Comment: @yes, I post another question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283760/js-and-css-are-not-loading-after-installation

Comment: If the current issue resolved with my answer then make it acceptable . Let me check your new question.

Comment: Chmod 777 ?? Are you serious?

Comment: @Black the pub directory should be writeable .What's wrong with that

Comment: @MahmoodRehman, If you are on a shared server, then other users can change files in your pub folder and manipulate your site as they wish or even delete files.

Comment: @Black You are right to some point. but the same thing can be done while we are giving to var directory. If you check on major tutorials and documentation it's suggested to give 777 to var and pub/static folders. I think there is no security breach for these folders.

Comment: Those tutorials are stupid and wrong. Of course it is a security breach, it always is. Cache files are stored in var/cache, so an attacker could change them to make your webserver play out his hacked version, for example. Or he can access your database dumps and steal them, or randomly delete files to sabotage your site. And Im sure there is no official documentation which recommends to set 777

Comment: Friends don't tell friends to `chmod 777 ...`