# JS and Css are not loading after Installation

Tags: magento2

( I know there are many article on this.Even try all )
Install fresh `Magento 2.2.6` with new DB, every thing smooth and but frontend is not loading `css` and `js`.

**store**

[image]

**VPS Server : Bluehost.com**

**Magento version: 2.2.6**

Already run following command

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`bin/magento cache:flush`

`bin/magento cache:clean`

`All necessary permission already assign to folders`

Even Change

`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`

to

`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Now dont know what else to do to fix it.

Comment: check in core_config_data table path = "dev/static/sign" Exist OR Not ??

Comment: @RkRathod, yes its exist and its value is `0`

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/259 check this

Comment: change your magento mode from default to developer in env.php

Comment: Show your current mode ? either its developer or default

Comment: yes its developer from beginning.

Comment: try to change the mode then run the deploy content commands.